# VNC to port 5900 on elastic beanstalk

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to expose port `5900` from this container: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

My `Dockerrun.aws.json` file has:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "selenium/standalone-chrome-debug",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5900"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/selenium"
}
```

When I `vnc://sample-env.abc123.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:5900/`, I am unable to connect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a load balancer in your EB environment? Did you open port `5900` in your security group?

Comment: Does ELB create a load balancer by default? I did not specify. Can I configure the security group in the console?

Comment: It will create an ELB by default if you don't specify that you are creating a single-instance environment. Yes you can configure the security group in the console.

Comment: Gotcha. I do not have an ELB. Should I configure through the console? Or is there a way to configure the security group via a configuration file?

Comment: You can configure it either way.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the help! I didn't realize I could edit the security group from the console. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to open port 5900 in the Security Group.

This can be done via the console.

See [Configuring the EC2 Instances in your Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html) for more details.